# How to fix the following partition layout to achieve what I want

Tags: windows, partitioning, grub, operating-systems, bootloader

After experimentation and installing & removing different OSs my partition table looks like>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ0zO.png)

I want to completely reinstall windows, with there being no association between the current windows OS to the new windows OS i.e. no windows.old folder when I install windows on the same partition there is a windows OS on. I also want the unallocated space to be allocated to the C partition. I also have a problem when I boot my computer with some grub bootloader that is annoying, which partition do I remove to remove it? Ideally, I would want to wipe everything and just install a completely fresh windows OS with no association to the old and no special bootloaders. How would I achieve this?

When I install windows from a fresh usb, I can only choose the current C partition leaving the unallocated space unused, and leaving the other partitions which I assume one of them is the grub bootloader.

[image]

Comment: " I can only choose the current C partition" not true, click the advanced options icon, delete all partitions then hit enter.

Comment: @Moab I just want to make sure I am doing it correctly. This is what it looks like https://i.imgur.com/aa33JAb.jpg . Are you saying I click on each individual partition and press format? I see no advanced options button

Comment: yes, highlight each partition and click Delete, this is if you want to delete everything and start fresh, you will wind up with one unallocated partition, then click next.

Comment: @Moab Did it and it worked thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight each partition and click Delete, this is if you want to delete everything and start fresh, you will wind up with one unallocated partition, then click next to install Windows.